# How to update a deleted file again from Webtorm to github?

Tags: git, github, webstorm

I wanted to gather all my repositories in one repository. Thus I deleted the repositories and tried to update them again into one folder. However every time I tried to push them from Webstorm to Github, it would say the deleted repository can't be found (of course) and failed. It seemed that the local files and the Github repositories were connected. Thus I want to know if there is a chance to rebuild the connection and put all the deleted files in the new folder. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf7Xh.jpg)
The blue ones are good while the black ones were folders updated and deleted before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already created your new GitHub repository, clone it to some new location, then copy all your local files and folders (except for `.git` folders!) to this location and push.
If the repository is not yet created, delete all `.git` folders from your local project and then share it on GitHub using `Import into version control/Share on GitHub`